# What to do when Wikipedia page has multiple 'wikitables' when web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

New to web scraping and want to get tables from wikipedia articles but often there are multiple wikitables and my code will only pull the first wikitable which is not what I want.

```
#My code:
url_3 = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Seattle_Seahawks_seasons'
response_3 = requests.get(url_3)
soup_3 = BeautifulSoup(response_3.text,'html.parser')
seahawks_list = soup_3.find('table',attrs={'class':"wikitable"})
seahawks_df = pd.read_html(str(seahawks_list))[0]
print(seahawks_df)

#Output
                    0                     1                   2                3
0  Super Bowl champions  Conference champions  Division champions  Wild Card berth
```

This is the first wikitable in the article and not the one I want. I'm unsure how to index to a different wikitable.

[Picture is a reference to the wiki page. I am trying to get the table below the highlighted
one but both tables have class='wikitable'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bisfI.png)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're finding this.
Instead of using `find`, using `find_all`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
url_3 = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Seattle_Seahawks_seasons'
response_3 = requests.get(url_3)
soup_3 = BeautifulSoup(response_3.text,'html.parser')
seahawks_list = soup_3.find_all('table',attrs={'class':"wikitable"})
seahawks_list[1]
```

And the `seahawks_list[1]` is what you want.
The output would be like this

```html
<table class="wikitable" style="text-align:center">
<tbody><tr>
<th rowspan="2"><a class="mw-redirect" href="/wiki/List_of_NFL_seasons" title="List of NFL seasons">Season</a>
</th>
<th rowspan="2">Team
</th>
<th rowspan="2"><a class="mw-redirect" href="/wiki/List_of_leagues_of_American_football" title="List of leagues of American football">League</a>
</th>
<th rowspan="2">Conference
</th>
<th rowspan="2">Division
</th>
<th colspan="5"><a class="mw-redirect" href="/wiki/Regular_Season_(NFL)" title="Regular Season (NFL)">Regular season</a>
</th>
<th rowspan="2"><a href="/wiki/NFL_playoffs" title="NFL playoffs">Postseason</a> results
</th>
<th rowspan="2">Awards
</th>
<th rowspan="2">Head coaches
</th></tr>
<tr>
<th>Finish
</th>
<th><style data-mw-deduplicate="TemplateStyles:r1038841319">.mw-parser-output .tooltip-dotted{border-bottom:1px dotted;cursor:help}</style><span class="rt-commentedText tooltip tooltip-dotted" title="Wins">W</span>
</th>
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Let pandas parse the tables. It will return a list of dataframes. Like stated before, you want the second table (index position 1)

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Seattle_Seahawks_seasons'
df = pd.read_html(url)[1]
```